# 'kedro' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, kedro

I am trying to install Kedro but I am getting this error. I know most of the time this error arises because kedro is not in my PATH. I tried adding the file path to my PATH and still getting the same error.
When I run:

`pip show kedro`

output:

Name: kedro
Version: 0.15.5
Summary: Kedro helps you build production-ready data and analytics pipelines
Home-page: https://github.com/quantumblacklabs/kedro
Author: QuantumBlack Labs
Author-email: None
License: Apache Software License (Apache 2.0)
Location: c:\users\vince\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages
Requires: pyarrow, anyconfig, PyYAML, requests, SQLAlchemy, tables, xlrd, cookiecutter, fsspec, pip-tools, toposort, s3fs, pandas, python-json-logger, xlsxwriter, click
Required-by:

I get the file location, and that is what I was trying to add to my path. I am assuming I am using the wrong location, but I am not sure which file location to add to my PATH.

What I added to my path: c:\users\vince\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages

Comment: Can you show us your current `$PATH` and the output of `pip show kedro`?

Comment: I added the output and the location I added to my PATH in the OP

Comment: Can you look inside your `C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts\` to see if there's anything about `kedro` in there? If so, try adding that to your `PATH`?

Comment: On Windows you need to add the location of `kedro.exe` to your PATH rather than the location of `kedro` package installation. As per @ZainPatel's comment, those can appear in `C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts`

Comment: Or something like `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\Scripts` depending on where this `Script` folder is located for the specific Python interpreter. To find out your interpreter executable location you can run from the terminal `where python`

Comment: I added c:\users\username\appdata\roaming\python\python36\scripts\kedro.exe, to no avail. @DmitryDeryabin

Comment: You need to add `c:\users\username\appdata\roaming\python\python36\scripts` rather. Another quick workaround is to run Kedro as a module: `python -m kedro run`.

Comment: This worked, thank you! @DmitryDeryabin

Answer (score 1):

To turn the comments into an answer:

With Python CLI tools on Windows, you need to make sure that your Python `Scripts` directory is in your `PATH`. The location of that directory depends on what version of Python you have installed, and you can look it up for your specific version. Common locations include (replace `Python37` with your version):

- `C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts`
- `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts`

NB: It should be the entire directory that is added to your `PATH`, not the path to the `kedro`executable itself.

Alternatively, you can run `kedro` as a module by running `python -m kedro`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding the path outputted by the command `which kedro` instead?
Did the package install successfully after you did `pip install kedro`?

Comment: I tried to run 'which kedro' and it returned a long statement that basically said it could not find it. If I run 'pip install kedro' it tells me that all requirements are already satisfied.

Comment: Try running `which pip`, and `which python` do the directories match up to the environment you are trying to use.  I have seen similar issues when environments get half activated/deactivated.  Like some others have said, its likely a path issue, but this may help figure out where the path went wrong.